# How to use Angular 2 for various sites & modules using PHP as backend?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, node.js

I would like to make more use of market-standards and therefore trying to start building my front-end with Angular 2, instead of my custom JS MVC-framework. However I feel getting stuck with Angular because of the things below. To describe my issues, I use a very basic example of a PHP-website with 2 simple modules.

In my current PHP-project I have 2 separate (non interrelated) modules, lets say a contact-module and a review-module, they are on the same page.

On the client side both modules download JSON-data and post JSON-data to the PHP-webservice running on port 80.

**Question 1**

Is it correct that for both (non interrelated) modules I need to create an Angular 2 app? So creating 2 Angular apps?

**Question 2**

Do you have to run per module an instance of "npm start", so that on save it will keep transpiling my project-files? This will lead to having many "cmd prompts" with "npm start" running in the background right? Now its only 2 cmd prompts, but what if my site contains 10 modules doing ASYNC-activity?

**Question 3**

Is it possible to share the JS-library files with various apps and within various sites?
So that it does not download all the 16.000 JS-files every time you try to do some simple ASYNC-download of JSON-data and add it to the DOM?

If yes, how?

So:

C:\angular\ -> JS-Library (containing 16.000 files.... :|)

---

C:\sites\site1\ -> uses C:\angular\

C:\sites\site1\contact-module\ -> uses C:\angular\

C:\sites\site1\review-module\ -> uses C:\angular\

etc.

---

C:\sites\site2\ -> uses C:\angular\

etc.

C:\sites\site3\ -> uses C:\angular\

etc.

How to share all those 16.000 files in the Angular JS-libraries within multiple modules & projects?

Per Angular 2 app it downloads via "npm install" more than 16.000 files....., even for the most simple application you can develop!

By having 2 simple modules, it will download 32.000 files & loading 100's of files in my webbrowser for just running 2 simple modules? (sorry but really thinking WTF!! What a waste and what an overkill, right?)

Ok, maybe you can JS-pack all those JS-files later on and combine it into 1 file. But still is this not overkill?

So, can I not for example share 1 Angular library with multiple Apps? Then it "only" requires 16.000 files...

Let's say you create 5 websites. For every website you have to add 16.000 JS-files, only because you need to do some simple ASYNC-request and add the JSON-date to your DOM. For this activity you already need to download 80.000 files (5 * 16.000)!

If it is also necessary to have several modules in a website requiring to do ASYNC-activity, like here the contact-module and the review-module, then it can easily become downloading millions of the same JS-files and using an awful lot of resources. And for every module to work having to use "npm install" and "nmp start" everytime to just work and see the results.. Having 10 "cmd prompt" screens running in the background to make this basic activity possible.

And all of this for just downloading some plain JSON-data from PHP-webservice and put it nicely into the dom?

**Question 4**

My main question, is the above the right / recommended approach? Not to start a discussion on how should you exactly use it, but is this a common way of working for PHP-website development and using Angular 2 for the frond-end? Or is there a better way of working?

Note, I am aware that PHP is in this scenario irrelevant, of course it can also be C# or JAVA as a back-end. But its to make the example more concrete.

**Question 5**

Then using the recommended TypeScript you will have to use "npm start" to transpile your files to JS and then it will run on localhost:3000.

I'm developing my sites in PHP and using Xampp on localhost port 80. Any experience of people that use Angular 2 for their front-end for their PHP-projects? How do you configure it so that it will refresh your localhost:80 page when you change something in your TS-file? And what if you have multiple (non interrelated) modules for which you use another Angular App? It cannot run twice on the same port right?

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your understanding is that you're mixing everything into one question: back-end (PHP), front-end (Angular), development setup (npm) etc. I'll try to give short answers to each of your questions.

**Question 1**

No, I wouldn't do create two angular applications. If you'll have a separate page for each module, you can use router to enable navigation without page reload.

**Question 2**

This depends on how you setup your development process. Usually, with modern building systems like webpack, you can configure module dependencies and how often each must built. This all can be managed through one command line instance.

**Question 3**

npm downloads 16000 files because it downloads sources along with built files. You'll use one built version in the production.

**Question 4**

I usually separate front-end and back-end development into different projects and treat them as completely separate applications communicating through REST interface.

**Question 5**

For usage of typescript, you'll have to use preprocessors which will be run by your building system. Try to google setting up angular 2 with webpack and a lot will be clearer to you.